What's the recommended approach for managing asynchronous callbacks in Dart when interfacing with native code using FFI
I'm working on a project that involves integrating native C code with a Dart application using FFI (Foreign Function Interface). I need to share TypedData between Dart and C, but I'm unsure of the best practices or the canonical way to handle this. Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on how to efficiently transfer and manage TypedData objects across the Dart and C boundaries without running into performance issues or memory management problems. Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.
I attempted to share TypedData between Dart and C by directly passing a Uint8List from Dart to C using FFI. I expected the data to be accessible in C as a simple array of bytes that I could manipulate. However, when I tried to access the data in C, I encountered issues with data corruption and unexpected memory behavior. My expectation was that the data would remain intact and accessible, but instead, the data appeared to be misaligned or incorrectly transferred, leading to incorrect results. I was hoping for a seamless data exchange between Dart and C without needing additional memory management or data conversion steps.
